# Writing code in c utilizing imported data from a tsv file

Tags: c, while-loop, printf, scanf, fgets

Question Prompt[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MnlP.png)

**I am very new to C and I didn't really understand this chapter in my text book. This is the final version of my code that I have written, although, I have been at this for 3 hours straight.(p.s. some of the code is intentially surrounded by slashes because of testing purposes.)**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   
   FILE* StudentInfo = NULL;
   FILE* Report = NULL;
   int x = 0;
   int Reader = 1;
   const int STUDENT_LINE_INFO = 50;
   char studentGrades[STUDENT_LINE_INFO];
   char firstName[25];
   char lastName[25];
   int score1;
   int score2;
   int score3;
   int studentAvg;
   /*int midterm1;
   int midterm2;
   int final;*/
   
   StudentInfo = fopen("StudentInfo.tsv", "r");
   
   while(fgets(studentGrades, STUDENT_LINE_INFO, StudentInfo)) {
      printf("%s", studentGrades);
      sscanf(studentGrades, "%25s %25s %d %d %d", lastName, firstName, &score1, &score2, &score3);
      studentAvg = ((score1 + score2 + score3) / 3);
   }
   printf("%d", studentAvg);
   

  /* Report = fopen("report.txt", "w"); 
  
   fprintf("%s", studentGrades);
   fprintf("Averages: midterm1 %d, midterm2 %d, final %d", midterm1, midterm2, final); 
   
   if (x >= 90) {
      fprintf(Report,"A");
   }
   else if ((x < 90) || (x >= 80)) {
      fprintf(Report, "B");
   }
   else if ((x < 80) || (x >= 70)) {
      fprintf(Report, "C");
   }
   else if ((x < 70) || (x >= 60)) {
      fprintf(Report, "D");
   }
   else {
      fprintf(Report, "F");
   }
   fclose(Report); */
   
   return 0;
}
```

I need some help please. I know this code is uncomplete but I dont know if it is even remotely close to what I need to be doing. Is this even the right approach?

Comment: What is your goal? One suggestion; test your code without using a file. Just hardcode a set of values and see if the rest of the code works. When all that is working, add the file input.

Comment: At the very top of the question there is a link that leads to the assignment I have. Its not very prominent. I am very new to posting on this site! It was question prompt 1 and next to it is the link

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, copy the text verbatim into your question. Yes, you can [edit] it.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". You need to be more specific to get good answers.

Comment: Inside the loop you do `studentAvg = ((score1 + score2 + score3) / 3);` each iteration through the loop you overwrite the value of studentAvg with the average of the current student.  Then after the loop you do `printf("%d", studentAvg);` which prints the average for the most recently read student read from the file.  If you want to save the averages for all the students you must do it inside the loop because after the loop all you have is the most recently read student.

Comment: Something like this: https://onlinegdb.com/gNN_B6Enh except I didn't do any error checking at all (just so the logic of the code was clear - you REALLY want to add all that error checking)

Comment: Oh, I was just reading the requirements again and it is quite clear that the first name and last name can be 25 characters which means the arrays that hold the names must be 26 characters long because you need to store an end of string termination character.